# Multilevel relationship whereHas on eloquent Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'd like to find

`Project::with('tasks.tags')->get();`

where only projects with a particular id of tag return in the result set.

For ex. I'd like to find a project with tasks and tasks with tags with only id of 1. In other words, filter the tasks return inside of the Project - Task relationship.

I have tried various ways but have failed so far.

I have tried:

```
$project = Project::with('tasks.tags')->whereHas('tasks', function($query){
            $query->whereHas('tags', function($query) {
                $query->where('id', 1);
            });
})->get();
```

And:

```
$project = Project::with('tasks.tags')->whereHas('tasks', function($query){
            $query->whereHas('tags', function($query) {
                $query->where('tag_id', 1);
            });
})->get();
```

This is how the relationships are setup:

In Project.php

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'project_id')->setEagerLoads([]);
}
```

In Task.php

```
public function tags()
{
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable')->setEagerLoads([]);

}
```

Note that relationship between Task and Tags is of morphToMany.

Any pointers?

Comment: Is there a reason you force eager loads to be unset in your relationship definitions?

Comment: Yes. The Tag class Task class are set as nested tree and I had to load their children recursively. Adding $with = ['children'] allowed me to easily load their children. If I do this manually, I have load 'children' recursively manually for each Task and Tag returned as children as well.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Did you try your first example with hard coded ids or with variables?

Comment: Hey, can you check the description again. Made some edit. I'd like to find all projects with a particular tag. I accidentally asked the wrong thing. I have been stuck on this problem for a few hours now and my head isn't right :D

Comment: To answer your question, yes I have tried it with hardcoded IDs.

Comment: That sounds good. What is the error you receive by the way? Have you tried checking the generated SQL statement (via debugbar or so)? I don't really have much experience with `morphToMany`, so if that's the issue, I won't be able to help I guess.

Comment: It doesn't through any error at all. The query just doesn't filter the tasks at all. What I'd like to do is filter the project's Task with only Tag of a particular ID. Say 1.

Comment: For Ex. Task::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function ($query){ $query->where('tag_id','1'); })->get();

Comment: I'd like to do this for the Project's task in the above query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Found the answer over here.](https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/multilevel-relationship-wherehas-on-eloquent-model)

```
Project::with(['tasks' => function($q) {
            $q->whereHas('tags', function($query) {
                $query->where('tag_id', 1);
            });
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need to scope the eager loading as well. Something like the following should work:

```
$project = Project::with(['tasks.tags' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 1);
}])->whereHas('tasks', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', 1);
    });
})->get();
```